# Как поменять звуковой сигнал в Ringtone Manager?

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Задача стоит следующая - нужно выводить звуковой сигнал при свёрнутом приложении. Для этого я использую Foreground Service. Проблема в том, что у меня не получается изменить тип звукового сигнала.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel("cid", "name",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            b.setChannelId("cid");
            mChannel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION), new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                    .build());
        }
```

Я пытался написать `mChannel.setSound(R.raw.beep_short)` но звук всё равно звучит стандартный. Подскажите пожалуйста, это вообще возможно сделать?

Comment: так вы пытаетесь в коде установить звуковой сигнал по умолчанию